# Js replace and Regex exclude a word

Tags: javascript, regex

I have this issue with regex, it doesn't  really have  friendly syntax for me :(.

Basically I need to match some text and wrap the matched word/letter with a `<strong>`.

```
html = html.replace(new RegExp('(' + word + ')', 'ig'), function ($1, match) {
                                return '<strong>' + match + '</strong>';
```

Now everything works fine except that in some occasion, the previously added `<strong>` get matched to messing up the html.

So I basically need the `html.replace` function to ignore any `<strong>` word during the matching.

I have tried to change `new RegExp('(' + word + ')'` with `new RegExp('(?!\<strong\>)(' + word + ')'` but I still have issue.

Ex.

```
'<strong>Alpinestars</strong> SMX Plus Gore-Tex Boots'.replace(new RegExp('(o)(?!</strong>)', 'ig'), function ($1, match) {
                            return '<strong>' + match + '</strong>';});
```

returns

```
"<str<strong>o</strong>ng>Alpinestars</str<strong>o</strong>ng> SMX Plus G<strong>o</strong>re-Tex B<strong>o</strong><strong>o</strong>ts"
```

Comment: ok just tried, unfortunately it is not working as expected. still the <strong> is matched if the word value is `O` for ex. ( while `o` is not matching it )

Comment: I think you just need `RegExp( word + '(?![^<]*</strong>)')`. You do not have to escape a `/` inside a regexp constructor.

Comment: @stribizhev looks better but still the closing tag is matched `</strong>`

Comment: Please post the input string and other pertinent code to repro.

Comment: I added an example using the @xdhmoore suggestion

Comment: in @stribizhev's code the closing tag is matched because it doesn't have parentheses around the "word". if you add those I think it'll work

Comment: Also, [just for fun](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags?rq=1), cause it's sortof related.

Comment: Confused. Why do you have `'(o)(?!</strong>)'`? Shouldn't it be `'(' + word + ')(?!</strong>)'`? That's what I was attempting to suggest in my answer.

Comment: I know that but I think it depends what you have to parse into html ... anyway I just need to exclude a word ... I think regex a perfectly suitable for this.

Comment: Yah, sorry I just think it's funny. What is the 'o'?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can check if you are not inside an element node with `(?![^>]*>)` look-ahead:

```js
function escapeRegExp(string){
  return string.replace(/[.*+?^${}()|[\]\\]/g, "\\$&");
}

var key = 'o';
var s = '<strong>Alpinestars</strong> SMX Plus Gore-Tex Boots';
var res = s.replace(RegExp(escapeRegExp(key) + '(?![^>]*>)', 'ig'), function (m) {
                            return '<strong>' + m + '</strong>';});
document.getElementById("t").innerHTML = res.replace(/>/g, "&gt;").replace(/</g, "&lt;");
```

```html
<div id="t"/>
```

You also do not need any capturing groups (*unless* you are using alternations like `boots|caps|hats`) and do not have to use `new` with `RegExp`. I also added an [`escapeRegExp` function from MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions) to escape special characters in `key` if any.

Comment: I updated your answer with what worked for me.  ( consider $key can be also a full word ... with your solution nothing was matched in that scenario )

Comment: @Wonderland, your update was rejected, as it changes the answer completely. If you want to share your solution, please post it as a new answer.

Comment: @WonderLand: If you need to perform a case-insensitive search, yes, add the `i` modifier. I added it to the code.

Answer (score 2):

You were close. You just had the order wrong. According to the following mdn page, the `x(?!y)` means: Matches x only if x is not followed by y.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp

So, this seems to work for me:

```
var word = 'and';
'dogs <strong>and</strong> cats <strong>and</strong>'.replace(
    new RegExp('(' + word + ')(?!</strong>)', 'ig'), 
    function ($1, match) {
        return '<strong>' + match + '</strong>';
    }
);
```

Comment: check my update on the question ( there are still some issues )